# MSVM_ComputerSystem WMI class returns only Hyper-V host

Tags: wmi, hyper-v

Having  a problem in listing list of virtual machine from Hyper-V host (Windows 2012 R2) using WMI query remotely. (select * from MSVM_Computersytem).

The query lists only Host system and no virtual machines are listed.

WMI query is ran in the context of domain user from a remote system and has all required permission to Hyper-V host’s WMI name space (\root\Virtualization\V2). 
There is no error in connecting to Virtulization\V2 name space.  I don’t see any WMI events in event logger as well.

With similar permission we are able to query WMI classes in root\cimv2 name space but unable to get data from WMI classes in root\virtualization\v2 name space

Virtual machines are listed when domain user provided with local admin rights of Hyper-V host.

The systems are in highly secured environment and we don't want to give local admin rights on Hyper-V hosts.

Domain user is also part of “Performance Monitor Users”,  “Distributed COM Users” and “WinRMRemoteWMIUsers” Windows groups

What additional permission is required to get list of VM’s remotely without giving local admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the user to "Hyper-V Administrators" local security group on the Hyper-V Server. For more details follow the below link:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e377ae58-8912-4f8c-8fbe-14955a483a52/msvmcomputersystem-wmi-class-returns-only-hyperv-host?forum=winserverhyperv