# Only host info listed using Msvm-Computersystem for hyper-v withC#

Tags: c#, controls, wmi, hyper-v

I am new to WMI classes and hyper-v , when i tried to get the info of host and all virtual machines through Msvm_ComputerSystem, it  turns out only host info shown, the codes as show below as (just very simple sample provided online), however i can get the virtual machine info when i used powershel l command of Get-VM, by the way, i am using hyper-v on win 10 and try to control it locally.any help will be highly appreciated.

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\root\\virtualization\\V2");
string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Msvm_ComputerSystem");
ObjectQuery vmquery = new ObjectQuery(query);
ManagementObjectSearcher vmsearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, vmquery);
ManagementObjectCollection vmCollection = vmsearcher.Get();
if (vmCollection.Count == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No virtual machine found");
    }
ManagementObject vm = null;
foreach (ManagementObject instance in vmCollection)
    {
      vm = instance;
      Console.WriteLine("\nName: {0} \nStatus:{1} \nDescription: ",
                vm["ElementName"].ToString(),
                vm["EnabledState"].ToString(),
                vm["Description"].ToString());


        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems like duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594441/msvm-computersystem-wmi-class-returns-only-hyper-v-host

I was able to resolve my issues by assigning my application's .dotnet user the "Hyper-V Administrators" role.

Answer (score 0):

Use the WMI Code Creator from MS Download it from [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=8572)

It will helps you check everything

my Sample code of C# to get List of VM

```
public void listvms()
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                  new ManagementObjectSearcher("\\root\\virtualization\\V2",
                  "SELECT ElementName FROM Msvm_ComputerSystem where Description='Microsoft Virtual Machine'");           
        if (searcher.Get().Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                vmnamelist.Items.Add(queryObj["ElementName"]);
            }
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice, anyway , I have solved the problem by running the visual studio as an administer, then all the information is listed.

Comment: Run as Administrator is mandatory that we need to do for everything